# Gas pedal is completely loose and car revs high 1997 Honda Civic

Tags: honda, civic, acceleration

so recently I tried to start my 1997 Honda Civic all that happened was that the engine revved extremely high and then I shut it off. The gas pedal has absolutely no resistance.

Comment: You have an vacuum leak

Comment: Does the pedal come up, or does it go to the floor and stay there? Needless to say don't try to drive it!

Comment: Did anyone work on it recently??

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the throttle linkage is sticky or is missing the spring that returns it to idle. Check under the hood on the throttle body. Another possibility is that the cable that connects you pedal to the throttle linkage either is stuck or came loose, but i'd check the linkage first.

You can look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9D0z-ddj2ww) for an example, although i do not know if it is from the correct model year and engine type.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend inspecting the air flow sensor on air intake tube. Even just disconnect it in that case car revs should run up and down. possibly clean the sensor with some electric cleaner spray and blow it with air to clean the dust off or just get a new one in automotive store for possibly under $10 or $20